# Inserting slack variables in LPP

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

If we have $P = \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \textbf{Ax} \leq b \}$ and after adding a slack variables we get,
$P^* = \{ (\mathbf x, \mathbf v) \in \ \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \mid \mathbf{Ax+v} = b, \ v\geq 0 \}$.

A is $m\times n$ matrix, $\mathbf{x}$ is an extreme point and $y$ constraints are active in $P$. How do I find how many constraints are active in $P^*$?

I know that $x \in P$ is an extreme point if $n$ linearly independent constraints are active at $x$, and $x$ is degenerate if more than $n$ are active.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \text{right: } & \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m \\ \text{wrong: } & \mathbb R^n \text{x} \mathbb R^m  \end{align} $$ I edited the question accordingly and did some other emendations. $\qquad$